# How to connect ads to adcreative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Is it possible to connect ad_id and adcreative_id, or we can connect only adset_id with adcreative_id?
And then every adsets's  adcreatives_id  distribute  for every ad_id in this adset_id?

If it is possible to connect ad_id and adcreative_id, what fields we have to load?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc for connecting ad to adcreate
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup

Ad creative is under ad, so you will need to connect the ad through the param, e.g. in cURL:

```
-F "creative={'creative_id':<AD_CREATIVE_ID>}" \
```